# Accessing COM Interface with JNA

Tags: java, com, jna

I'm trying to access the [IDesktopWallpaper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706946(v=vs.85).aspx) interface with JNA, but I've hit a wall.

I went through `ShOljIdl_core.idl` (from Windows 10 SDK) and discovered the GUID of the interface as follows

```
// IDesktopWallpaper
[
    uuid(B92B56A9-8B55-4E14-9A89-0199BBB6F93B),
    object
]
```

and the GUID of the concrete class that implements the interface

```
// CLSID_DesktopWallpaper
[uuid(C2CF3110-460E-4fc1-B9D0-8A1C0C9CC4BD)] coclass DesktopWallpaper { interface IDesktopWallpaper; }
```

So I followed the official example in the JDA github and wrote the following

```
@ComObject(clsId="{C2CF3110-460E-4fc1-B9D0-8A1C0C9CC4BD}")
public interface DesktopWallpaper extends IUnknown{


}
```

and in `Main`

```
Ole32.INSTANCE.CoInitializeEx(Pointer.NULL, Ole32.COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
try {
    Factory factory = new Factory();
    try {
        DesktopWallpaper dw = factory.createObject(DesktopWallpaper.class);
    } finally {
        factory.disposeAll();
        factory.getComThread().terminate(1 * 1000);
    }

} finally {
    Ole32.INSTANCE.CoUninitialize();
}
```

But the `factory.createObject(DesktopWallpaper.class)` throws `No such interface supported(HRESULT: 80004002) (puArgErr=)`and I don't know how to get around this or why it is happening.

Can any experts enlighten me on what's happening? (I am a complete noob) I will provide any further info that's necessary. Can JNA achieve what I want or do I have to use something else like Com4j?

Comment: Does...it work if you use the GUID for the `IDesktopWallpaper` instead of the class? Just throwing a guess.

Comment: By the way, here's a C++ example of the same thing: https://github.com/mvaneerde/blog/blob/master/desktopwallpaper/desktopwallpaper/main.cpp

Comment: @cubrr No sir it does not, I've tried it, and I believe conceptually the factory requires an actual concrete implementation of the COM interface to instantiate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**TL;DR**](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jna-users/8TrdagbvMJE/KX4gVSkkEQAJ)

After a lot of googling, I finally got it to work. The problem (at least to my current understanding) is that the current JNA helpers only work with interfaces that inherit from `IDispatch`. So if the interface in question such as `IDesktopWallpaper` does not inherit from `IDispatch`, then one should use vtable for function calls. I got this information from [**this**](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jna-users/8TrdagbvMJE/KX4gVSkkEQAJ) amazing Google forum post in which the poster also provided a code sample that got me started.

Here is some working code for the `SetWallpaper()` function:

```
public class DesktopWallpaperHandler extends Unknown{
    private static final GUID CLSID_DesktopWallpaper = new GUID("{C2CF3110-460E-4fc1-B9D0-8A1C0C9CC4BD}");
    private static final GUID IID_IDesktopWallpaper = new GUID("{B92B56A9-8B55-4E14-9A89-0199BBB6F93B}");

    private DesktopWallpaperHandler(Pointer pvInstance) {
        super(pvInstance);
    }

    public static DesktopWallpaperHandler create(){
        PointerByReference p = new PointerByReference();

        WinNT.HRESULT hr = Ole32.INSTANCE.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DesktopWallpaper, null, WTypes.CLSCTX_SERVER, IID_IDesktopWallpaper, p);
        COMUtils.checkRC(hr);

        DesktopWallpaperHandler handler = new DesktopWallpaperHandler(p.getValue());

        return handler;
    }

    public void SetWallpaper(WTypes.LPWSTR monitor, WTypes.LPWSTR wallpaper){
        int result = this._invokeNativeInt(3, new Object[]{this.getPointer(), monitor, wallpaper});
        COMUtils.checkRC(new HRESULT(result));
    }
}
```

And then in `Main`:

```
Ole32.INSTANCE.CoInitializeEx(Pointer.NULL, Ole32.COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
try {
    WTypes.LPWSTR path = new LPWSTR("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Desktop\\1.jpg");
    DesktopWallpaperHandler handler = DesktopWallpaperHandler.create();
    handler.SetWallpaper(null, path);
} finally {
    Ole32.INSTANCE.CoUninitialize();
}
```

The original motive to use `IDesktopWallpaper` was to access the fade in transition effect, and now that can be done by adding the following:

```
User32.INSTANCE.SendMessageTimeout(User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow("Progman", null), 0x52c, 0, 0, 0, 500, null);
```