# Unable to access the IActiveDesktop interface with JNA (No such interface supported(HRESULT: 80004002)

Tags: java, windows-7, jna

I'm trying to change the desktop wallpaper on windows 7 with the IActiveDesktop interface. So I start my project and I first use the [SystemParametersInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) method using the [User32](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/User32.html) class. But there isn't fade effect and I can't modify the image position. After some research, I found the [IActiveDesktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nn-shlobj_core-iactivedesktop) interface and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016328/accessing-com-interface-with-jna). I took the answer and I adapt it. But when I running my code, it throw `Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMException: No such interface supported(HRESULT: 80004002)`.

Here you can find my code:

First the class which represent the IActiveDesktop interface

```
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.COMUtils;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.Unknown;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.*;
import com.sun.jna.ptr.PointerByReference;

import static com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Ole32.INSTANCE;

public class ActiveDesktop extends Unknown {

    // {75048700-EF1F-11D0-9888-006097DEACF9}
    // {F490EB00-1240-11D1-9888-006097DEACF9}

    private static final Guid.GUID CLSID_ActiveDesktop = getGUID("{75048700-EF1F-11D0-9888-006097DEACF9}");
    private static final Guid.GUID IID_IActiveDesktop = getGUID("{F490EB00-1240-11D1-9888-006097DEACF9}");

    private static Guid.GUID getGUID(String guidStr) {
        Guid.GUID guid = new Guid.GUID();

        INSTANCE.IIDFromString(guidStr, guid);

        return guid;
    }

    private ActiveDesktop(Pointer pvInstance) {
        super(pvInstance);
    }

    public static ActiveDesktop create(){
        PointerByReference p = new PointerByReference();

        WinNT.HRESULT hr = INSTANCE.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ActiveDesktop, null, WTypes.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IActiveDesktop, p); // THE EXCEPTION IS THROW HERE
        COMUtils.checkRC(hr);

        return new ActiveDesktop(p.getValue());
    }
}
```

And the Main which just load the Ole32 librairy and IActiveDesktop interface:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Ole32;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ole32.INSTANCE.CoInitializeEx(Pointer.NULL, Ole32.COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

        try {
            ActiveDesktop desktop = ActiveDesktop.create();
        } finally {
            Ole32.INSTANCE.CoUninitialize();
        }
    }
}
```

After a lot of googling, I cannot find an answer. Can anyone help me? May be the answer is [where I found this code...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016328/accessing-com-interface-with-jna) In this case, please explain me what's wrong. Thank you.

NB: I'm french so my english isn't perfect. I'm sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. Which is to replace `Ole32.COINIT_MULTITHREADED` by `Ole32.COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED` when initialize Ole32.

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering if you can provide the full working code to set a wallpaper with smooth transitions. Using the code you provided, I can't figure out how to actually set the wallpaper. I can get the code to compile, but I don't know how to use the ActiveDesktop desktop instance to set the wallpaper. It would be great if you showed how you use the desktop instance to set the wallpaper. Thanks!